# Sending holiday wishes while waiting for interview response

Tags: interviewing

I went to an interview about 3 weeks ago, and during that time they told me there would be a part two interview with another person.  I got an email from HR saying that they're highly interested in me, but because of the holidays they will let me know about part two after the first of this year.  I'm assuming that I'll have the second part of the interview sometime this week.

Is it OK to send Happy New Year emails to them while I'm waiting for the second part of the interview?

Answer (score 7):

I would not recommend doing this.

If you were told they would get back to you after the holidays then I would wait until the end of the week of January 9th before sending an inquiry to avoid being perceived as pesky.

At that point, there is no harm in send a polite inquiry as to the status of the position.

Comment: Since the country is not mentioned, might want to wait a little bit longer if it's in eastern europe (and several other countries) where christmas is celebrated after new year.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to look desperate, but you could try:

> Thanks for getting back to me. I hope you had a wonderful [insert
>   holiday of choice].
>
> I look forward to hearing from you shortly.
>
> Many thanks

Comment: I think I'm just going to wait for the second part of the interview.  Especially since HR send me an email saying they will get back to me after the holidays.  Plus, this way, I can tell them Happy New Year in person.